# How to get JSON output with Karate & Junit5?

Tags: bdd, karate, junit5, atdd

I am using com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate and it is generating the HTML report only but I would like to have JSON output.

I looked at the [code](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit5/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/junit5/Karate.java#L94) however it is by default generating the HTML output only by calling `Engine.saveResultHtml()` method.

May I know what options we can use to get the JSON output instead of HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [parallel runner](https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution).

The JUnit runners are only intended to be used in dev-mode and the HTML report is good for trouble-shooting tests.

Otherwise all teams use the cucumber-html-report, especially in a CI build - which depends on the JSON output you are referring to: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I am running it as a Junit test from IDE however it's not been picked up my maven test, do I need to do anything to enable it?

Comment: @ernitingoel maybe. read the docs please, tests for maven should end with `Test` or you can specify the test in the `maven-surefire-plugin`

Comment: Thanks, it was my bad, somehow it imported org.junit.Test instead of org.junit.jupiter.api.Test